# question about GO ON

Tags: meaning-in-context

The below sentence is from Longman dictionary, used to explain the usage of 'go on'. My question is whether the latter speaker agrees to have another drink or not.

> go on: used when you are agreeing to do something or giving permission for something.
>
> 'Are you sure you won't have another drink?'
>   'Oh, go on then.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Go on

has the meaning

> go ahead  *(AmE)*
>   continue on  *(AmE, BrE)*
>   carry on  *(BrE)*

it is often used in BrE, so the person did have another drink.

Here is an excellent take on the famous phrase "[the show must...go on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=827EAYtM6XQ&t=0m11s)".

Sometimes "then" is added

> go on then

Sometimes, "if you must" may be added to show a backhanded approval

> go on then, if you must *(with a wicked smile)*

To encourage on (a male)

> Go on my son!